# Get specific row out of mysql database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, command

I am working on a project, which needs me to get specific data from a database.
Let's say I have a value (UserID) and I need every other value that is in the same row as the specified UserID.

I am working in PHP on a raspberry.

Here is my database:

[image]

Here is the code I use to contact the db and (try) to get the "Raumname".
As you can see on the picture, there is a value called UserID, and it is twice in there. One time there is "Raum1" next to it, and the other time there is "Raum2" next to it.

Now, I need my Code to output me "Raum1" and "Raum2".

But with my current command I only get "Raum1".

```
      <?php
  try
   {    
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx.xx.xxx","xxx","xxxx","xxxxx");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$anmeldecode = $_GET['anmeldecode']; 
$query = "SELECT Raumname From UserinRaum r INNER JOIN Benutzer u ON u.Anmeldecode = r.UserID WHERE $anmeldecoder.Anmeldecode = '$anmeldecode'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo $row[0].",".$row[1].",".$row[2].",".$row[3].",".$row[4].",".$row[5];
mysqli_close($con);
}
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
          ?>
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Paste your code here, please. It's simple.

Comment: Add some code please.

Comment: Your question is similar to have an answer related to `mysqli_fetch_array()` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` but the issue is you can't receive an answer because no one knows where to start from. Look up [How to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here

Comment: Please look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answers. I added now the code

Answer (score 1):

```
You have mistaken in query:

use below query:

SELECT Raumname From UserinRaum r INNER JOIN  Benutzer u ON u.Anmeldecode = r.UserID WHERE u.Anmeldecode = '$anmeldecode'";

you need to use alias u instead of $anmeldecode
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"SELECT Raumname From UserinRaum r INNER JOIN  Benutzer u ON u.Anmeldecode = r.UserID "
. "WHERE $anmeldecoder.Anmeldecode = '$anmeldecode'";
             ^ Remove with alias name u
```

To

```
"SELECT Raumname From UserinRaum r INNER JOIN  Benutzer u ON u.Anmeldecode = r.UserID "
. "WHERE u.Anmeldecode = '$anmeldecode'";
```